# How to hide the circle in RadioButton control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have various RadioButton control inside a GroupBox control. Each one represents a coin denomination, when I select one the program does some logic with the selected coin. That works correctly, but I want to remove the RadioButton circle (the white one). Check the attached image:

[image: Coin denominations]

How I can remove the circle in a RadioButton control?

Comment: do you want to remove the circle or the rectangle around it? or even the whole rectangle including the circle?

Comment: The white rectable is just for spotlight the circle in the screenshot. I want to remove the circle, @isi .

Comment: Why don't You use `Image` control instead of `RadioButton` then and just save in Your code which image was last clicked? I suppose this would work as You expect and would be the easiest solution.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better, if you use buttons instead and put the coins as background Image? The only method to remove the circles is to inherit the radio buttons and draw it yourself. See Adrian's answer.

Comment: @ElMac , I need to make an EXCLUSIVE selection over coins, RadioButton controls is the most logic way (in my perspective). Thanks.

Comment: ListView is not possible?

Comment: You can implement the exclusive choice by yourself saving information about last clicked coin using a variable in code handling `Click` event on all of the `Image` (or `Button` or `ImageButton`) controls. This may be easier than overriding control rendering method.

Comment: I wrote too quick about `ImageButton` and `Image`, because it seems they're not available in WinForms. Sorry for the confusion. You can still use `PictureBox` or `Button` controls anyway.

Comment: Why to use radioButton in your case? Use PictureBox and it's several clicking events...

Answer (score 8):

The easy way: Change the RadioButton's `Appearence` property to `Button` value.

[RadioButton.Appearance Property (System.Windows.Forms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.appearance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: That is the solution indeed. I was not sure if that was a property of the button or of the radio box.

Comment: Anyway to change the background of the radiobutton once it becomes a "button" mine is white...

Comment: @Bowenac , do you want to change the RadioButton's background color?

Comment: @JohnOrtizOrdoñez yes when I set the radio button to be a button. It ends up with a white background. I am using two different circle images, one without a checkmark, one with a checkmark. But since it adds a white background and border its not going to work. Think I am just going to use picturebox and label...

Comment: @Bowenac Have you test with the Appearence properties (BackColor, FlatAppearence, etc.)?

Comment: @JohnOrtizOrdoñez yea it didn't work, I could only set a color, transparent wouldn't work. I ended up using pictureboxes, and changed checked unchecked on the click events for each "button" etc. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only method is **visual inheritance**, you have to create a new class that derives from  **RadioButton class** and to override the method **OnPaint**

```
class ChangedRadioButton : System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        // your modifications
    }
}
```

Comment: Then draw a rect with the background color above the dot part ;) But this will make the control wider than neccessary, wont it?

Comment: Thanks @Adrian. I have found a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the "Appearance" field in the object properties from "Normal" ==> "Button"

[image: checkbox properties]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31749967)